# connecting PIC 18f4455 to labview

Tags: labview, pic

I need to read data from a usb port sent by a PIC 18f4455, the data is sent by bulk, and the data will be displayed in labview (think of [this](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jnn4VliE1Og&feature=related))

Is it possible to get this data in labview? Could you give some pointers?

Comment: Does the usb act like a serial port? In this case you should send/receive commands with serial read/write functions. If not there must be a library for communication.

Answer (score 1):

Labview is a great data acquisition tool for all sorts of data & buses.

If you have control over the format of the data from the PIC i think you will find this even easier as any limitations or difficulties you find with the labview side of reading data, you may be able to rectify easier by modifying the output of the PIC.

I would probably look at serial over USB type interface to your PIC. There are libraries and drivers for this type of interface on both the PIC and LV side.

Answer (score 1):

If the data is sent via a bulk USB-Channel you will need to create a Raw USB-Driver using the VISA Driver Wizard which can be found in your *National Instruments* start menu directory. After you created and installed that driver, you can access the raw USB bulk channel in LabView using VISA. You will also find a small test panel for it in the *Measurement and automation explorer*.

Comment: Some more info on the NI forums. Intaris has written a series of posts on [Raw USB-drivers](http://forums.ni.com/t5/LabVIEW/Nugget-2-of-n-USB-Control-transfers-using-VISA/td-p/757011). However further links seem to be getting broken.[part 1](http://forums.ni.com/t5/LabVIEW/Nugget-1-of-n-GEtting-started-with-USB-communication-via-VISA/td-p/743518)